# DataContractSerializer with abstract (base) / concrete (inheriting) classes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

Given this code

```
public override void Serialize(BaseContentObject obj)
{
    string file = ObjectDataStoreFolder + obj.Slug + ".xml";
    if(obj.GetType() == typeof(Page))
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof Page));
        XmlDictionaryWriter myWriter =
            XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(new FileStream(file, ileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write),
                                             Encoding.UTF8);
        dcs.WriteObject(myWriter, obj);
        myWriter.Close();
    }
    else if(obj.GetType() == typeof(Image))
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof Image));
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

is there a way to do something like this

```
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
// this fails however, compiler error
```

and get rid of those if() statements above? The constructor of DataContractSerializer there expects Type or Namespace but it does not work with obj.GetType().

My class hierarchy is as follows:

BaseContentClass (abstract)

Page (concrete, inherits BaseContentClass)

Image (concrete, inherits BaseContentClass)

...

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about this [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404901.aspx) then the following code will compile fine:

```
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
```

As the constructor expects a type parameter.

Comment: I just tried it again in some other place and it does work indeed, so I really don't get it where did my error before come from. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Tell the serializer what to anticipate:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Page))]
[KnownType(typeof(Image))]
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseContentObject { /* ... */ }

[DataContract]
public class Page : BaseContentObject { /* ... */ }

[DataContract]
public class Image : BaseContentObject { /* ... */ }
```

Then you can use `new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BaseContentObject ))` for everything.

Comment: This looks interesting. However, on my abstract class I currently do not have [DataContract] attribute (only inheriting classes are decorated at the moment). Should I decorate abstract too?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use generics.
The helper can looks like:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T t, IEnumerable<System.Type> types, bool preserveReferences)
    {
        StringBuilder aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter aStreamWriter = new StringWriter(aStringBuilder))
        {
            DataContractSerializer aDCS;
            using (XmlTextWriter aXmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(aStreamWriter))
            {
                aDCS = new DataContractSerializer( typeof( T ), types, int.MaxValue, false, preserveReferences, null );

                aDCS.WriteObject(aXmlTextWriter, t);
            }
        }
        return aStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Generics will allow you to serialize any type you want without using if statements.