# How create Response back in XML format in WCF using Soap?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a WCF service(using Soap not REST) that Authenticate user, if the authentication fails I need to send a response back to client as a XML with Status code and status Message. I am not sure how to create response back to client in WCF?
That is my Service now.

```
    [ServiceContract]
   public interface IAcqtion
   {

    [OperationContract]
    bool Authentication(CommonLibrary.Model.AuthHeader Authentication);

    [OperationContract]
    string ProcessXML(CommonLibrary.Model.TransferData dto, bool Authenticated);



}
```

That is my test client that is calling this service:

```
        string rtn = "";
        Service.Client client = new Service.Client();
        Service.AuthHeader authentication = new Service.AuthHeader();

        //Pass username and password to Authenticate Service
        authentication.Username = "no";
        authentication.Password = "no123";

        //Pass PartnerID
        authentication.partnerID = 15666;

        bool auth = client.Authentication(authentication);
        Service.TransferData dto = new Service.TransferData();
        dto.xml = textBox1.Text;
        rtn = client.ProcessXML(dto, auth);
```

after bool auth = client.Authentication(authentication); I need to return XML to client with response that has a status and code.

Solution can be find in this: 
I can put the response back in XML.

[DataContractSerializer with abstract (base) / concrete (inheriting) classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056596/datacontractserializer-with-abstract-base-concrete-inheriting-classes#)

Comment: Just define your model for your return type - you do not need to handle xml yourself, if you have ServiceContracts, OperationContracts and DataContracts.

Comment: @Grumbler85 now my service returns rtn that is only test to client. I want to return XML with 2 nodes.

Comment: You need to change the return type of the `Authentication` method.  By default WCF will return XML, so there's nothing you need to do to make that happen.  If you want a specific format of the XML, then @Grumbler85's direction is correct - look into DataContracts.